# How to find Integration for a number of values in a column using array?

Tags: c

```
499183e+04   407257e+02   208773e+00      395     420
153463e+04   828733e+02   221093e+00      820     840
418161e+04   116941e+03   232724e+00      1160   1180
384500e+03   151044e+03   241853e+00      1500   1520
880331e+03   265567e+03   288564e+00      2645   2665
261537e+03   295819e+03   299508e+00      2945   2970
792049e+03   328865e+03   309009e+00      3275   3300
607461e+03   379468e+03   336309e+00      3780   3810
707934e+03   480620e+03   370690e+00      4790   4820
```

---

The above file is a text file that I am using.
I am trying to find the integration of a gausian function by reading columns using simpsons rule. Somewhere I am making a mistake and that's why I am not getting correct result.
The array's values (f[j] and g[j]) are not correct at the first place.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.`

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include<math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#define Max 9


      fclose(fptr);

    return 0; 

}
```

Comment: This seems like a very good time to learn how to *debug* your programs. For example, with a *debugger* you can step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. If you simplify your expressions so you can see the intermediate results as well, then that should be enough to see when and where your program goes wrong.

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need arrays here, because you only ever look at the current line. You can make all `x[Max]` and so on scalers. This should make your expressions easier to read, too.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, the values are incorrect after calculating the gaussian.  Your gaussian function itself looks correct, but I'm suspecting your input data is not.

Using the coefficients you have provided, then `f[0] = a[0] * exp(-840510.774820);`.  `exp(-840510...)` is a very small number (`~6.4e-365030` according to Wolfram Alpha) which simply is too small to be represented by a 32-bit float (or 64-bit double for that matter), so it gets rounded down to `0.0`.  This makes `f[0]` zero as well.

If the input data is actually what you want to calculate, then you will need to restructure your calculations so they can be calculated using the 32-bit floats you are using.  This could mean storing `log(f)` as an intermediate value instead of `f` directly, as `a[0] * 840510.77` can most likely be represented in 32-bit float without problems.  But then you would need to modify the rest of the algorithm accordingly.

Another solution would be to use an [arbitrary precision library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software) to do your calculations.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think that's the issue.